# Error finding class that test runs from, even though I use an automatic test creation function in IDE

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm using PHPUnit, PHPStorm.

Now, my actual file being tested is located in `root->foo->config`

Next, if I select the file I want to test, and right click, new phptest, I get the screen below:

[image: PHPStorm test function start]

So everything looks ok so far. Everything is pre-entered automatically.

So my ip_require.php goes into `root->tests->foo`

My test file contains the following:

```
<?php

namespace config;

use foo\ip_request;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ip_requestTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testGetRealIpAddr()
    {
        $local = new ip_request();
        $this->assertEquals('127.0.0.1', $local->getRealIpAddr());
    }

}
```

Inside my phpunit.xml, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<target name="test">
<phpunit
        bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
        colors="true"
> <!-- changed from vendor/autoload.php-->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name = "Website">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
</target>
```

And all I have inside my bootstrap.php is

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\foo\ip_requestTest.php';
```

I Get the errors on the bootstrap.php preview:

[image: bootstrap.php error screen]

Everything I hover over looks to be pointing in the right direction on the classes.

If I click and follow the class from the test file, it takes me to the correct location

My PHPUnit is installed to the latest version, verified in the command line, and inside composer.json

```
"require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "9.3",
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  },
```

Any ideas? I've run out of links to try...

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, to get past the bootstrap.php page at least.

```
include __DIR__ . '/../foo/config/ip_request.php';
```

I then still had a similar error message in my terminal, but the thing that finally got my tests working was I made sure that composer.json had the same version of PHPUnit.

Once they where the same it worked!

Comment: these tests are not supposed to be run in a browser. just in case if you wonder why things appear complicated maybe. run them within phpstorm or on the commandline. Phpstorm  allows you to configure directly from composer.json. There you require Phpunit and then you're normally ready to go and you can execute the unit-tests on the green arrow-right buttons in the Phpstorm editor.